# iPhone 4S before upgrades

Tags: iphone

I have upgraded my iPhone 4S to the iOS 8.0 version and it has made my phone extremely slow. Can I restore my iPhone 4S to its original state before any upgrades were done?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - 'No'

Apple stopped signing iOS 7 in Sept 2014 for any device capable of running iOS 8.

There is no going back, even if you have a legitimately downloaded ipsw file for iOS 7, as it will never validate.

Answer (score -1):

No, but if you irreparibly damage it (eg. send it through a full washer and dryer cycle), you can buy a $200 replacement from Apple through their Out Of Warranty Replacement Program and that 4s will likely have iOS 7 installed.

Comment: That likelihood is purely based on speculation

Answer (score -2):

I was told by an associate at a Radio Shack that it could be restored to iOS 7 by doing the following:

1. Delete your iTunes program from your computer.
2. Find an older version of iTunes on the internet that has the iOS 7 "attached" to it.
3. Download this iTunes to your computer.
4. Restore your phone to factory settings.
5. Connect your phone to your computer and it will automatically update to the iOS 7.

I have not tried this myself, as it seemed too complicated for me. So I have no idea if it actually works. But if anyone wants to give it a shot or has any feedback on whether this works, I would be interested to hear it.

My iPhone 4s is basically unusable since updating to iOS 8.

Comment: Note that the version of iTunes will not be an official Apple on  so you need to check it for Trapans and viruses etc

Comment: Note also that you can download perfectly legitimate versions of old iOSes from many sources - yet if Apple are no longer signing them it will get you nowhere. I'd totally ignore the Radio Shack advice; it wasn't well thought through at all.